# How to add a progress listener to t:inputfileupload?

Tags: java, jsf, file-upload, progress-bar, tomahawk

so far my attempt

here is the jsp part

```
 <h:form id="fileUploader" enctype="multipart/form-data" target="upload_target" >
            <h:panelGrid columns="4" width="100%">
                  <t:inputFileUpload id="file" value="#{FIleuploadservlet.uploadedFile}" required="true" />
                   <h:commandButton value="Submit" actionListener="#{FIleuploadservlet.uploadDirect}" onclick="setFormAction();" />
            </h:panelGrid>
```

managed bean...

```
public void uploadDirect(ActionEvent ae)
    {
        HttpServletRequest request=(HttpServletRequest) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequest();
        HttpSession session=request.getSession();

        try
        {
        byte[] data = new byte[(int) uploadedFile.getSize()];
        uploadedFile.getInputStream().read(data, 0, (int) uploadedFile.getSize());

        System.out.println("savefile===="+uploadedFile.getName());
        File file=new File("c:\\file");
        if(!file.exists())
        {
            file.mkdirs();
        }
        FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("c:\\file\\lantern.avi");
        fileOut.write(data, 0, data.length);
        fileOut.flush();
        fileOut.close();


        }catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: JSF 1.x or 2.x? If 1.x, are you using any ajaxical component library?

Comment: jsf 1.x no am not using any ajaxical component library.What i have thought of is i know where the file wil be stored in the server.i can also know the total file size as --uploadedFile.getBytes().length.Shud i write a servlet that compares this two and a javascript that calls this servlet every 100-200ms.That wil be pretty hectic .Is there a simple way to do so.

Answer (score 0):

use richfaces library. Its display is good and have a progress bar.